# Do pre-made Traveller 5 adventures exist, in the book or separately?

Tags: published-adventures, traveller

I am going to be picking up a copy of the Traveller 5 core book. Neither I nor any of my group have ever played Travller before. Does the book come with an adventure for new players?

Either way, are there pre-made adventures I could purchase and use for low level characters and which ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: there are no pre-made adventures for T5, in the book or, as far as I'm aware, otherwise.

The long answer is: players new to Traveller are probably better served with Classic Traveller or Mongoose Traveller rather than T5.  I don't have any experience with T5, but it's my understanding that it's closer to a Traveller toolkit than a ready-to-run RPG. Both CT and MGT are ready out of the box and, while neither has an intro adventure in the core book, both have several published adventures available. Both CT and MGT also have a large catalog of supplements available when you're ready to expand the game past the core.

Comment: If you pick up either the Classic Traveller "Starter Edition" or "The Traveller Book", both have adventures included in their texts.

Comment: +1 for recommending CT or MGT over T5 for new players; T5 is very hard to read and understand unless you already know the assumptions built up by previous editions.

Answer (score 5):

Cirque by Greg Lee is written explicitly for Traveller5.  It was funded on Kickstarter on March 31.  It is available from Greylock Publishing -- refer to Cirque's Facebook page for more info:

https://www.facebook.com/CirqueT5Supplement

Having said that, I also would recommend first buying classic Traveller -- in particular, The Traveller Book -- due to its accessibility and ease of use.

http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/80192/CTTTBThe-Traveller-Book

Alternately, the entire classic Traveller corpus is available on CD-ROM from Far Future Enterprises.